# Late 80s short-lived sci-fi/supernatural series where the main characters are ghosts who solve mysteries/help people

Tags: story-identification, tv, ghost

In the first episode, the two main characters die. Afterwards, they go around solving mysteries or helping people or whatever. IIRC, in the first episode the man rescues the woman from the ocean. I believe it was an NBC show, and it wasn’t on long.

Comment: Can you remember any of the mysteries they solve/people they help? Any specific episode plots? Remember one of those could really help someone find this for you. If you want to add anything else you can [edit] your question.

Comment: Are you sure they ***both*** died? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_and_Hopkirk_(Deceased)

Comment: Nightmare cafe? Circa 1992 NBC the intro features the two dead main characters in the water.

Comment: Lucas Bachmann, that’s it! Thank you! Only it was the 90’s and not the 80’s-1992, to be exact!

Answer (score 8):

*[Nearly Departed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearly_Departed)*, an American sitcom starring Eric Idle and Caroline McWilliams that aired on NBC on Monday nights from April 10, 1989 to May 1, 1989, itself an updated version of *[Topper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topper_(film))*.

> The series focused on English professor Grant Pritchard and his wife Claire who are killed in a rockslide. They return to their home as ghosts to find plumbing contractor Mike Dooley and his wife Liz, son Derek, and his father, Jack, living there. Grandpa Jack was the only one who could see and hear the Pritchards. In exchange for continuing to live in the house as ghosts, the Pritchards would mediate through Grandpa Jack and try to help the Dooleys with their problems. In one such instance, Derek was doing poorly in school because he was intimidated by bullies; Grant and Claire use their abilities to scare off the bullies.

As a Python fan, I was really rooting for Eric but I could not last 5 minutes.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how this matches the OP’s description?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I expanded your answer.

Comment: It was on NBC, it had two dead people as characters, it was broadcast in the late 80s and it wasn't on for long.